# odp.net DateTime.MaxDate

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net

When I insert a maxdate in an Oracle Date field:

```
using (OracleCommand Cmd = new OracleCommand("insert into test (mydate) values (:mydate)", OracleConnection))
{
    Cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":mydate", DateTime.MaxValue));
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

And try to retrieve the value:

```
using (OracleCommand Cmd = new OracleCommand("select mydate from test where mydate=:mydate", OracleConnection))
{
    Cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":mydate", DateTime.MaxValue));
    object MyDate = Cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

The MyDate object keeps null. Which means it can not read the record back. Is this a bug? Some rounding mismatch somewhere?

Comment: Is Oracle's maximum date value earlier in time than `DateTime.MaxValue`?

Comment: Ok, but I use exact the same parameter for the select and the insert.

Comment: It, had to do with the MaxValue, a new DateTime(2999,1,1) does work. I think I will use another date as default. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `Date` in the database is not like the `DateTime.MaxValue`.
It's neither the same datatype nor the same precision.

Try this query:

```
OracleCommand Cmd = new OracleCommand("select dump(mydate), dump(:mydate) from test where rownum=1", OracleConnection)
```

The results would be something like this:

```
dump(mydate):  Typ=12 Len=7: 199,199,12,31,24,60,60
dump(:mydate): Typ=180 Len=11: 199,199,12,31,24,60,60,59,154,201,156
```

This means that the value in the DB is of type `Date` and contains time with seconds but no millisecondas, whereas the parameter is converted to a `timestamp` datatype which does hold millisecondas.

So, if you do want to use it in your `where clause` try it like this:

```
using (OracleCommand Cmd = new OracleCommand("select mydate from test where trunc(mydate, 'mi') = trunc(:mydate, 'mi')", OracleConnection))
         {
             Cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":mydate", DateTime.MaxValue));
             object MyDate = Cmd.ExecuteScalar();
         }
```

Note that this will truncate the seconds as well

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing `DateTime.MaxValue` from c# to oracle let's say `timestamp` parameter, the value will be: `10000/01/01/ 00:00:00`
Year: `10000` (yes, ten thousand, it's not typo). I believe this is the bug between c# and oracle OLEDB provider

Most probably you get exception on insert and insert fails. 
To confirm the year value, use the next expression:
`EXTRACT (YEAR FROM CAST(yourparameter AS DATE))`

Good luck!